# Yoast and another plugin

Tags: plugin-development, categories, seo

So, Yoast plugin is sayin that - **You have far too little content. Please add some content to enable a good analysis.**

But I have content.. I know that Yoast not working together with other plugin, because i use plugin for posts (article plugin)
Question is how i can make that two plugins work together?

Answer (score 0):

Yoast only looks at `the_content` - that is, the content in the main, default WP editor. If your other plugin stores the content of posts in any other way, Yoast won't see that content. You'll probably be best off just disabling content analysis in Yoast if you'd like to continue using that plugin. Or, you can look for a different way - other than the article plugin - to accomplish your publishing goals but still store the content in the main editor, thus allowing Yoast to analyze it.